# Django custom middleware rendering has no csrf token

Tags: python, django, middleware, django-csrf

My custom middleware returns a rendered response (with `RequestContext`).

It seems this causes the `csrf_token` context var to be set to `NOTPROVIDED` ([Djangos sentinel value for not provided](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/core/context_processors.py#L18)), and `{% csrf_token %}` gives no output, as [the CSRF middleware is called on `process_view`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/middleware/csrf.py#L96), which I'm assuming we never get to run in this case.

The middleware-rendered response isn't complicated, and it is a rarely used special-case, however the CSRF token is needed for changing language, as that is a POST request to Djangos built-in `set_language` view.

What's the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Can we see the middleware you're building?

Comment: [Sure, pastie here](http://pastie.org/private/vrhotvmgmf4cvevjjpbz5g), but there's not much relevant to show besides what I already explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, why you don't have the csrf token available in process_request, is that token is set in `process_view` of the csrf middleware, which is run after each middleware's `process_request`, so you need to move your code into `process_view` instead:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if some_clause:
        return render(request, 'foo.html', {'foo': 'bar'})

    return view_func(request, view_args, view_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [1.5 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware):

> process_request() should return either None or an HttpResponse object.

Try:

```
class FooMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        if some_clause:
            return render(request, 'foo.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
        return None
```

Comment: Yes, mine returns an `HttpResponse` object in this case.

Comment: Thanks - but a python method without a return clause, automatically returns `None`. Besides, this is only related to cases where `some_clause` is `True`, and we do return a rendered page. When you say it works, do you mean `{% csrf_token %}` in `foo.html` gives a valid token?